# Wordpress Simple Shortcode Exercise

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Iam new to Wordpress and try to learn how to use Shortcodes / create own Shortcodes.

I started with something really simple from the Wordpress Shortcode documentation

```
// [bartag foo="foo-value"]
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'foo' => '',
), $atts );

    if ($a['foo'] = "red") {
         $output = "<span style='color:red;'>foo = {$a['foo']}</span>";
    }
    elseif ($a['foo'] = "blue") {
        $output = "<span style='color:blue;'>foo = {$a['foo']}</span>";
    }
    else {
        $output = "foo = {$a['foo']}";
    }
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

Its quite basic PHP. One Attribute ("foo"). My goal is to output the text in different colors conditionally.
So if I type [bartag foo="red"] in the editor. The text should be red. Same with blue.
For some reason the output is allways red.

I know thats not quite modular programming but Iam still learning :)

Does someone know whats my mistake?

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` !== `===`. You're using the wrong operator in your `if`, `elseif`, etc. Use `===`

Comment: Oh ok that solved the problem. I allways thought "===" is only for boolean stuff like true and false?!

Comment: `===` tests for value *and* type. See the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a value instead of checking for one -- you have to use the equality operator  instead:

```
if ($a['foo'] === "red") {
     $output = "<span style='color:red;'>foo = {$a['foo']}</span>";
}
elseif ($a['foo'] === "blue") {
    $output = "<span style='color:blue;'>foo = {$a['foo']}</span>";
}
else {
    $output = "foo = {$a['foo']}";
}
```